# Is there a faster way to compute and resuse this pdf?

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to compute the pdf of a multivariate normal in mathematica.

```
T = 2;
M1 = Table[Indexed[m1, {i, j}], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}];
A = Table[Indexed[a, {i, j}], {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
Cmat = Table[Indexed[c, {i, j}], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 2}];
Q = DiagonalMatrix[Table[Indexed[q, {i}], {i, 1, 2}]];
Sigma = 
  DiagonalMatrix[Table[Indexed[sigma, {i}], {i, 1, 4}]];
rowvecy1T = Table[RandomReal[], {i, 1, 4*T}];
vecx1T = {{0.991684}, {0.525986}, {0.47597}, {0.510281}};
rowvecx1T = {0.991684, 0.525986, 0.47597, 0.510281};
vecx0T1 = {{0.839535}, {0.298143}, {0.991684}, {0.525986}};

tilmean = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[T], Cmat].vecx1T;
tilcov = KroneckerProduct[M1,{{1, 0.960603}, {0.960603, 1}}];
```

When I compute

```
mx = Transpose[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[T], A].vecx0T1][[1]];
PDF[MultinormalDistribution[mx, 
  KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[T], Q]], rowvecx1T]
```

Mathematica is very quick to give an expression...
However, when I try

```
my = Transpose[tilmean][[1]];
PDF[MultinormalDistribution[my, tilcov], rowvecy1T]
```

it's very slow, taking almost 40 seconds.

Both command calls have the same computational complexity, I think. So, I tried different matrices, and there's something in the matrix tilcov that makes mathematica lag many seconds... My problem is that I don't know what's the problem with tilcov. I've tried putting the matrix M1 symmetric, but I still get a similar amount of lag.

Also, later on I'll have to reuse this pdf, but with some of the numbers updated, and the 40 seconds awaiting time is just too much for the purpose of the main programme...

Comment: I'm surprised you get anything.  `rowvecy1T` is not defined in your code.

Comment: @JimB I forgot to add it... I hope now it's ok. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try a direct approach:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Det[2 π tilcov]^(-1/2) Exp[-(rowvecy1T - my).Inverse[tilcov].(rowvecy1T - my)/2];]
(* {0.404807, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[PDF[MultinormalDistribution[my, tilcov], rowvecy1T];]
(* {15.2071, Null} *)
```